# Core Plot: Show yearly labels on the x-axis for daily values

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, charts, core-plot

For the plot values in my Core Plot chart I am displaying `NSDate` based values on the `x`-axis.
The values encompass many years and are plotted on a daily basis.

I would like to display labels on the `x`-axis for each year or month, but not for each day. This is why I can't use the labeling method shown in the Core Plot example app `DatePlot`.

Currently I am creating the labels manually (as shown in the following code snippet). Unfortunately, this solution leads to the issue shown in the screen shot below (the label for the year 2001 is too close to 2002).

```
[sortedArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:  
   ^(Price *priceItem, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        
NSDateComponents *yearComponents = 
   [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit 
   fromDate:price.dateTime];
NSDateComponents *monthComponents =
   [gregorian components:NSMonthCalendarUnit 
   fromDate:price.dateTime];       
NSInteger year = [yearComponents year];
NSInteger month = [monthComponents month];
if (month != previousMonth) {
   [minorTickLocations addObject:
   [NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:idx]];
   previousMonth = month;
}
if (year != previousYear) {
   CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] 
   initWithText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", year]
   textStyle: axisTitleTextStyle];
   newLabel.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(idx);
   newLabel.offset = x.labelOffset + x.majorTickLength / 2.0;
   [xAxisLabels addObject:newLabel];
   [majorTickLocations addObject:
       [NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:idx]];
   previousYear = year;
   }
}];
```

[image]

I am wondering if there is a better way to code this using standard Core Plot methods.

It would be great if the date formatter behaviour could be used to show only years (`YYYY`), month and years (`MMM-YYYY`) or only months (`MMM`).

### Edit

As Eric recommended in his post, I am converting my dates to fractions of year in order to be able to use `CPTDateFormatter`. This is how I set up the chart (Initially, I just want to plot a tick per calendar year):

```
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
CPTCalendarFormatter *calendarFormatter = [[CPTCalendarFormatter alloc]
   initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter];
calendarFormatter.referenceDate = [sortedPrices[0] 
   valueForKey:@"dateTime"];
calendarFormatter.referenceCalendarUnit = NSYearCalendarUnit;
x.labelFormatter = calendarFormatter;
```

This is how I convert my initial integer based index to a "fraction-of-year" based index:

```
- (NSArray*)indexArrayOfDatesArray:(NSArray*)dates
{
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] 
   initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *startDate = [sortedCommonSharePrices[0] valueForKey:@"dateTime"];
NSDateComponents *yearComponents = [gregorian components: NSYearCalendarUnit
   fromDate:startDate];
NSUInteger startYear = yearComponents.year;
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:dates.count];
[dates enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDate *date, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
   NSDateComponents *yearComponents = [gregorian 
        components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
   NSInteger years = [yearComponents year];
   NSUInteger numberOfDaysSinceStartOfYear =
        [gregorian ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
         inUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit forDate:date];
   
   NSUInteger totalNumberOfDaysInYear = 365;
        
   double fractionOfYear = (double)numberOfDaysSinceStartOfYear /
      (double)totalNumberOfDaysInYear + (double)years - (double)startYear;
        
   [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:fractionOfYear]];
}];    
return array;
}
```

This seems to work ok, but seems to be a lot of code (any thoughts on improving the code ?).

### Question

When zooming and panning (using `plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo`) I want to set the x-axis labels to the new date range (based on the number of days in the new plot range. However, I get an incorrect number of ticks and wrong labels (please refer to the screenshot below).

How would I need to set the labeling parameters to get the labeling right?

Thank you for help!

Code snippet from `plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo`:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSDayCalendarUnit 
   fromDate:newStartDate toDate:newEndDate options:0];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
CPTCalendarFormatter *calendarFormatter = 
   [[CPTCalendarFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter];
calendarFormatter.referenceDate = [sortedPrices[0] valueForKey:@"dateTime"];
                     
if (components.day < 365) {
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"ddd-MMM-yyyy";
   calendarFormatter.referenceCalendarUnit = NSDayCalendarUnit;
} else if (components.day < 365 * 2) {
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MMM yyyy";
   calendarFormatter.referenceCalendarUnit = NSYearCalendarUnit;
} else if (components.day < 365 * 4) {
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"qqq yyyy";
   calendarFormatter.referenceCalendarUnit = NSYearCalendarUnit;
} else {
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy";
   calendarFormatter.referenceCalendarUnit = NSYearCalendarUnit;
}
CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 10;
x.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.1);
x.minorTicksPerInterval = 1;
x.labelFormatter = calendarFormatter;
```

[image: Wrong ticks and labels]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provide your own labeling policy, like this:

```
...
CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
int totalNumberOfYearsToShow = 3;
int startYear = 2010;
int i = 0;
NSMutableSet *xLabels = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:totalRecords];
NSMutableSet *xLocations = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:totalRecords];

while (i < totalNumberOfYearsToShow)
{
    NSNumber *xData = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(i + startYear)];
    CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[xData stringValue] textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
    label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromInt([xData intValue]);
    label.offset = x.majorTickLength;

    if (label)
    {
        [xLabels addObject:label];
        [xLocations addObject:xData];
    }

    i ++;
}


x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
x.axisLabels = xLabels;
x.majorTickLocations = xLocations;
...
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't use the labeling method shown in the Core Plot example app DatePlot.

Why not? With the fixed interval labeling policy, just set the `majorIntervalLength` to the equivalent of one year and use a `CPTCalendarFormatter` or `CPTTimeFormatter` to format the labels.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Eric! What would be the equivalent of "one year" for `majorIntervalLength` when each year has a different number of daily periods (e.g. some years have only 20 daily periods, some 250 periods or 300 periods)? Can I still use `CPTCalendarFormat` in this case?

Comment: `CPTTimeFormatter` is probably the best solution for this use case. Use the `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` for the x-values of each data point instead of the index. Since the reference date is in seconds, you would set the `majorIntervalLength` to one year in seconds (60*60*24*365.242 = 31,556,908.8).

Comment: Thank you, @Eric! I believe your solution would create a label whenever a year (365 days) has passed (e.g. when my first date is `05-15-2007`, I would get a label at `05-14-2008`). However, I would like to create a label whenever a new year has started (e.g. putting a label between `12-31-2007` and `01-03-2008`, the first business day in the new year). This is why I compare the year for each date with the year of the previous date and put a label whenever the date has changed. But I believe my solution is not the most elegant one.

Comment: Using the fixed interval labeling policy, just make sure the `labelingOrigin` falls on the new year. Choose an origin point close to your date range to minimize the rounding errors caused by small variations in the length of a year (watch out for leap years especially).

Comment: Alternatively, use a `CPTCalendarFormatter` and convert the dates on the x-axis to fractions of a year. This will eliminate the leap year problems.

Comment: Thank you @Eric Skroch for your last suggestion! I have changed my code accordingly, which seems to work fine when the chart is plotted initially. In `plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo`, I would like to adjust the ticks and labels based on the new plot range and have added the code above (please refer my edited question) to handle this. However, I get wrong labels and ticks. Do you have an idea on what might be wrong? In addition: How can I get the ticks plotted (I get only labels, but no tick marks)? I tried for hours but didn't find the solution to this. Thank you!